# What makes yarn fast? Key Differences between npm and yarn?

Tags: npm, dependency-management, web-frontend, yarnpkg

It's been a long time me and my team are working with **`npm`** for frontend dependency management for a bunch of projects.

Mean while I came across **YARN** another dependency management, everybody is buzzing about it. So before switching to it I would like to what makes Yarn fast?

On [Yarn site](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) they claim `caching` is reason behind being `Ultra fast`, npm also does the caching and similar stuff. So what's the big difference?

Comment: Yarn is NPM compatible, bower isn't. Please edit your question to be more specific. "vs" will attract downvotes, since it implies opinion-based question.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi thanks for suggestion

Answer (score -1):

Yarn is fast because does it indeed caches dependencies. If you start from scratch it tries to do things in parallel. That also speeds up things noticeably.